# Rails Exporting CSV ignore blanks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to create a simple CSV export in Rails. The export works fine except when deleting/archiving table items. I'm guessing this is because the export is encountering blanks.

This is working:

```
= link_to transactions_path(format: :csv) do
```

Except when there is a item missing from the transaction.

Tried this

```
= link_to transactions_path(format: :csv,skip_blanks: true) do
```

but I still get a ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE when calling the export

TransactionController:

```
respond_to :html, :json, :csv

def index
   @shops = current_user.shops

   respond_with(@shops) do |format|
     format.csv do
       response.headers['Content-Type']              = 'text/csv'
       response.headers['Content-Disposition']       = "attachment; filename=transactions-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}.csv"

       render inline: @shops.to_csv
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the TransactionsController for the action that is erroring out.

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper added above.

Answer (score 6):

Change to_csv to pass skip_blanks.

```
 @shops.to_csv(skip_blanks: true)
```

Comment: It would be great if this worked, it's so simple, but I'm still getting an ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Answer (score 3):

If you want a link to download a CSV file, you should use `send_data` instead. If you want to display the file in the browser, use `render text: @shops.to_csv`

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

```
respond_to :html, :json, :csv

def index
  @shops = current_user.shops

  respond_with(@shops) do |format|
    format.csv do
      send_data @shops.to_csv, type:'text/csv', filename: "transactions-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}.csv"
    end
  end
end
```

Change your link_to back to what you had before.

`= link_to transactions_path(format: :csv)`

Comment: Thank you, this is better! However this still doesn't solve the original request. Any ideas on ignoring blanks?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `send_data`:

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data @current_user.shops.to_csv, filename: "transactions-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}.csv" }
    end
  end
```

Also, is the `to_csv` an instance method?